# Dismiss keyboard when user taps outside the textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard when the user selects something other than the `textFiled`. I tried the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mytextField1.delegate = self;
    mytextFiled2.delegate = self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];    
}
```

This didn't work. I then tried `[... resignFirstResponder]` in `touchesBagan`, and that didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong? Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tap gesture to the view (not the text field) so that you know when someone taps the view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then when that method is called, resign first responder to dismiss the keyboard.

```
- (void)viewTapped
{
    if (self.textField.isFirstResponder) {
        [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't I just do: `[self.view endEditing:YES];` and take away the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a UITapGestureRecognizer on the text field's superview that dismisses the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer. And also save the current focused TextField at activeTF. You need to set the current view controller as the delegate of UITextField(s).

```
UITextField *activeTF;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    .......

    UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:dismissTap];
}


- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    if (activeTF) {
        [activeTF resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

#pragma mark - TextField Delegate

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    activeTF = sender;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    activeTF = nil;
}
```